# When the user is already authenticated, it displays the LoginViewController about half a second before going to the MainController

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication

I'm new to the swift world and I'm developing my application using Firebase features.
I followed the procedures in the Firebase documentation and managed to implement the Authentication Controllers normally, except for one detail that I find strange. When the user is already authenticated, it displays the LoginViewController about half a second before going to the MainController. Is that correct?
I would like the app to go directly to the MainController if the user is already logged in. Thank you.

Follow the code:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var textFieldPassword: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldEmail: UITextField!

var authStateListener: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    authStateListener = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
        if user != nil {
            self.callMainController()
        }
    }
}

func callMainController() {
    if let storyboard = self.storyboard {
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainController") as! UITabBarController
        self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        Alert(controller: self).show(message: "Error on show MainController")
    }
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(authStateListener!)
}

@IBAction func didTapLogin(_ sender: Any) {
    if let email = self.textFieldEmail.text, let password = self.textFieldPassword.text {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            print("User Logged")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a slight delay between when the content is loaded and Firebase updates the user auth

Comment: I'm aware of this delay. I wonder if this behavior when implementing an application is normal, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Hey buddy this is not the right way to do it, you have to check if user is logged in inside app delegate and set window.rootviewcontroller accordingly so you will not see any flicker , there is method inside firebase sdk to check if user is logged in or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the login status in `AppDelegate` and set rootViewController in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FirebaseApp.configure()

        var initialViewController: UIViewController!

        if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
          initialViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController")//replace your mainviewcontroller identifier
        } else {
          initialViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController")//replace your loginviewcontroller identifier
        }

        window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
      }
```

Comment: See my edit, I think it would throw an error without the variable.

Comment: @J.Doe Yes. I missed it.

Comment: I tried to do it here however I get a black screen. It looks like the view is not being displayed, but the views are connected to the controllers correctly.

Comment: @ThomasMarques Its because you have the view controllers in storyboard. Above code if for viewcontrollers created programmatically. Wait. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got it that way. Thanks a lot for the help.

```
    var initialViewController: UIViewController!

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
        initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController")
    } else {
        initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController")
    }

    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```